# Use a shell script output as variable in html

Tags: html, bash, shell, sh

I'm learning HTML and I have a question on working with shell scripts.

For example, I have a shell script, which looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

//Get input of text field in HTML
if [$INPUT = "testString"]
then
    echo 'true'
fi
```

And I have an HTML file, which looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf8">
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
              <input type="text">
              <input type="button" onclick="">
//onclick: execute shell script with value of text field and if shell script returns true, load another page. 
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, I want to know how I can execute the .sh script and how I can handle the output.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Use php instead of bash, this is straightforward to adapt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this can be answered in the scope of a stackoverflow question, but I'll give it a go. Ultimately I think you have two options:

- Learn Javascript.
- Learn CGI (or a more modern web solution, if bash isn't a must)

The first thing you need to know about is client-side vs server side programming. If you're executing an on-click, it's going to have to be client-side, which usually means it would have to be in Javascript; now there are ways to use other languages in your browser, but for now, just assume it has to be Javascript.

If you want to run a shell script as part of your web system, you're going to have to do some server side programming. For the simple example you're talking about I would suggest learning about CGI; Common Gateway Interface. For real stuff I get the impression it's pretty much obsolete at this point, but for your simple case, it's simple and will be a good foundation to learn more useful stuff such as Python WSGI, PHP, or FastCGI, etc.

You don't really on-click (not technically correct since AJAX, but assume so for now) a server-side program; you set the forms action to call the server side program.

```
<form action="serverside.cgi" method="POST">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Now you need a CGI enabled web-server, and a basic tutorial in CGI (if you want to use bash, but please consider Python(Flask) and PHP, or the web functionalities/tools of any other language you may be familiar with as well) which is well beyond the scope of what could reasonably be presented as a stack overflow answer.